# iOS image picker is not showing images first time even after granting permission

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, phassetcollection, ios15.2

When I fresh install the app and try to add photos even after granting the permission the image picker (I am using QBImagePickerController) can't load any albums or image. But if I terminate the app and relaunch it works. It's happening after iOS 15.2 update. Here is the log while running in simulator.

```
Failed to load library: Error Domain=com.apple.photos.error Code=41011 "Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization}


failed to load photo library PHPhotoLibraryMainQueueQoS with url file:///...., Error Domain=com.apple.photos.error Code=41011 "Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization}

[GatekeeperXPC] Failed to open photo library file://..../data/Media/, Error Domain=com.apple.photos.error Code=41011 "Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unauthorized access: client does not have valid TCC authorization}
```

Comment: Same here - a second start works

Comment: Yes, the Same things. first time not work. even I'm use below 2 library: OpalImagePicker, AssetsPickerViewController.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have anyone got the solution for this problem. Need help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the issue still exist please check below link:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696804

"Before iOS 15.2 version we could register PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self) without authorization, in iOS 15.2 it is not possible, you will get an error. You have to request authorization(requestAuthorization(_:)) for register PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)."

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Call PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self) after receiving status from authorization(requestAuthorization(_:))